# How do I get the attribute value as string with ScraPY xPath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

The Scrapy documentation says that to get a string representation of an element I have to do "string()"

so I did:

```
for url in response.xpath('string(//a[@class="thumbnail"]/@href)'):
        print(url)
```

Without the string it prints all  but with string() there it just prints the Selector for the first element then closes the spider. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.xpath('string(//a[@class="thumbnail"]/@href)') #this is a selector object (list of selectors)`

```
response.xpath('string(//a[@class="thumbnail"]/@href)').extract() # in your case href attribute (list of hrefs)


for url in response.xpath('string(//a[@class="thumbnail"]/@href)').extract():
        print(url) #actual href as found in html (can be relative or absolute)
```

more info in docs [selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

Comment: Thank you, but string() still doesn't work for me even with 'extract()'. I tried 'extract()' alone and it worked so I don't know why....

Comment: you can use `.getall()` this will get you what you want as well `response.xpath('string(//a[@class="thumbnail"]/@href)').getall()`